# What is the right way of implementing C++ setters in char array wrapper class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, setter

I'm working on the class that simply contains a character array and it's size (length in bytes). At the moment, I want to overload '+' operand for this class (to implement concatenation). Constructors work fine. Objects are created and I can see their fields and values in the debugger. I'm stuck at the point where '+' is used (main(line 13)). Code compiles well, without even warnings, but as I run it, my program fails with "invalid pointer message". And I found where exactly that invalid pointer is. It is in '+' implementation (BufferArray.cpp, line 39). When i call SetBuffer, char array is assigned properly (I saw it's value 'qwasd' in the operator implementation scope), but right at the next line it's vanished when I call SetSize. I have no idea why.

What is wrong with my setters and how can I implement '+' operand in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Here's the code I work with:

**BufferArray.h:**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef BUFFERARRAY_H
#define BUFFERARRAY_H
class BufferArray {
public:
    BufferArray(char* reservedPlace);
    BufferArray();
    void SetSize(int sz);
    int GetSize();
    void SetBuffer(char* buf);
    char* GetBuffer();
    BufferArray operator+ (BufferArray bArr) const;
    virtual ~BufferArray();
private:
    int size;
    char *buffer;
};

#endif  /* BUFFERARRAY_H */
```

Implementation is in the next file **BufferArray.cpp:**

```
#include "BufferArray.h"

// Constructors.
BufferArray::BufferArray(){
    size = 0;
    strcpy(buffer, "");
}
BufferArray::BufferArray(char* reservedPlace) {
    size = strlen(reservedPlace);
    buffer = reservedPlace;
}

// Getters and setters.
void BufferArray::SetSize(int sz)
{
    size = sz;
}
int BufferArray::GetSize()
{
    return size;
}
void BufferArray::SetBuffer(char* buf)
{
    buffer = buf;
}
char* BufferArray::GetBuffer()
{
    return buffer;
}

// Operator +.
BufferArray BufferArray::operator+ (BufferArray bArr) const
{
    char tempCharArray[strlen(buffer) + strlen(bArr.GetBuffer())];
    strcpy(tempCharArray, buffer);
    strcat(tempCharArray, bArr.GetBuffer());
    BufferArray tempBA;
    tempBA.SetBuffer(tempCharArray);
    tempBA.SetSize(strlen(bArr.GetBuffer()) + strlen(buffer)); // Vanishes buffer field.
    printf("%d",tempBA.GetSize());
    return tempBA;
}

// Destructor.
BufferArray::~BufferArray() {
    // Destroy the pointer.
    delete [] buffer;
}
```

And the **main** function:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "BufferArray.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    BufferArray ba1;
    char tmp1[3] = "qw";
    char tmp2[4] = "asd";
    ba1.SetSize(strlen(tmp1));
    ba1.SetBuffer(tmp1);
    BufferArray ba2(tmp2);
    BufferArray ba3 = ba1 + ba2;           // Runtime error is here.
    cout << ba3.GetBuffer() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in BufferArray::operator+, tempCharArray is a temporary buffer that will be destroyed when the function completes. There a basically two ways to handle this:

1/ allocate the temporary buffer with new[] in operator+, that way you'll make sure the buffer survives the call to operator+ but you'll either have a memory leak or require the caller to invoke delete[] later on, which is rather clumsy and error-prone

2/ or better yet, modify setBuffer so it does an internal copy of the buffer and add a call to delete[] in your own destructor :

```
BufferArray::~BufferArray() {
    delete[] buffer;
}

void BufferArray::setBuffer(char *otherBuffer) {
    buffer = new char[strlen(otherBuffer) + 1];
    strcpy(buffer, otherBuffer);
}
```

Note that you'll have to modify the constructor so it also copies the input buffer (otherwise you'll have an illegal call to delete[] when the object is destroyed), and then you may want to overload the copy-constructor and assignment operator to prevent shallow copy which would result in double-deleting the buffer.

In actual production code, you'd want to use a managed pointer of some sort to avoid doing the delete yourself (e.g. std::vector or boost::shared_array), but for homework the above solution should be fine.

On a side note, don't forget to add +1 when using strlen to determine the size of your buffer ;)

Comment: I tried to watch what strlen(buf) returns when the 'buf' is passed as an input paremeter and found that it works properly (it returns 5). Thanks for the answers! I'm trying to fix my class now. I'll accept the apropriate answer after got it working.

Comment: It works! In addition to changes in the setter and constructor code where 'new' keyword was used in order to create char arrays, I had to dynamically allocate BufferArray tempBA like this: BufferArray *tempBA = new BufferArray(tempCharArray); And then I return *tempBA, not tempBA.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `new` to create these char arrays, otherwise the temporaries (like tempBA) are destroyed when you exit the scope.

```
void BufferArray::SetBuffer(char* buf)
{
   buffer = new char[strlen(buf)+1]; //edit, my size param wasn't necessary
   strcpy(buffer,buf);
}
```